# how to jsonify all responses within a flask blueprint

Tags: flask

I'm using the Flask Blueprint module to create a REST api for my application.  Since it's a REST api, every response needs to be encoded in JSON.  Currently, I have to make sure to end every method with `jsonfify(my_data)`, which is kinda repetitive and easy to forget.  Is there a way to tell Flask that I want all responses coming out of my blueprint to be jsonified?

I tried doing:

```
@blueprint_object.after_request
def after_req(response):
    return jsonify(response)
```

but that didn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.  And in case you're wondering, I know that the Flask-Restful extension does this, but I'm not using the extension because it's not flexible enough for what I want.

Comment: `blueprint_object` is your app?

Comment: Can show us a simple view and how you register it in the blueprint? Depending on how you're doing that there might be simple solutions.

Comment: why not use flask_restplus ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small snippet to add a `json_route` method to an already existing blueprint (instance of the `Blueprint` class). You can call this instead of `a_blueprint.route` to decorate a view which returns json compatible content:

```
import types

from flask import jsonify


def json_route(self, rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", f.__name__)

        def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return jsonify(f(*args, **kwargs))

        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, new_f, **options)

        return new_f
    return decorator

a_blueprint.json_route = types.MethodType(json_route, a_blueprint)
```

Then you can declare your views this way:

```
@a_blueprint.json_route('/test')
def test_dict():
    return {'foo': 'bar'}
```

If you want this decorator in multiple blueprints, it would probably be worth subclassing Flask's Blueprint class to add the method there.

If you don't want to use a different decorator (`json_route` instead of `route`), you could directly override this method on the instance, although it's kinda dirty.